# Conditional concatenation of two columns in a Data Frame

Tags: pandas

I am currently stuck with an operation on a dataframe.

Here is the Dataframe :

```
Origin  Destination Route
CDG JFK CDG-JFK
ORY RUN ORY-RUN
BOS GIG BOS-GIG
EZE CDG EZE-CDG
CDG DPS CDG-DPS
SIN CUN SIN-CUN
JNB RAK JNB-RAK
LIM JFK LIM-JFK
RUN GIG RUN-GIG
CDG DPS CDG-DPS
CUN RAK CUN-RAK
CDG ORY CDG-ORY
BOS CDG BOS-CDG
SIN JNB JNB-SIN
LIM SFO LIM-SFO
```

I would like my Route column to be a concatenation of the Origin Column and the destination with the following condition :

(Origin < Destination means in the explanation that origin is alphabetically before destination).

I would like to have the following logic :

If Origin < Destination : 
       Route = Origin +"-"+ Destination 
Else : 
       Route = Destination +"-"+ Origin

For instance : if origin = AAA and destination = BBB then route = AAA-BBB
But if origin = DDD and destination and CCC then route = CCC-DDD.

How could I do it ?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`np.sort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html) + `map`:

```
#import numpy as np
df['Route'] = list(map('-'.join, np.sort(df, axis=1)))
print(df)
```

Output

```
   Origin Destination    Route
0     CDG         JFK  CDG-JFK
1     ORY         RUN  ORY-RUN
2     BOS         GIG  BOS-GIG
3     EZE         CDG  CDG-EZE
4     CDG         DPS  CDG-DPS
5     SIN         CUN  CUN-SIN
6     JNB         RAK  JNB-RAK
7     LIM         JFK  JFK-LIM
8     RUN         GIG  GIG-RUN
9     CDG         DPS  CDG-DPS
10    CUN         RAK  CUN-RAK
11    CDG         ORY  CDG-ORY
12    BOS         CDG  BOS-CDG
13    SIN         JNB  JNB-SIN
14    LIM         SFO  LIM-SFO
```